# Connect to a non locally hosted database when using MAMP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, hosting, mamp

im looking to launch a site soon that will have lots of user data on it.

For easier testing and uploading etc for changes i want to know if i can work on my MAMP site, whilst using directly the database from the live site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used MAMP and my database connected fine from one at the hosting company (not locally) if you use Joomla you can change the configuration.php file to point to your live database.